# Using GNU C Libraries and other Data structure libraries on Mac/Windows/Linux.?

Tags: sql, c, libraries, portability

I want to know if the C libraries system/string/data structure/data base etc are platform dependent.?

what are the things of these libraries that are dependent on a specific platform.?
like how a regular expression/string manipulation/sql connectivity etc libraries are dependent on a platform.?

can I use them on any platform for File I/O/Paths etc
just like we do things in python using the sys/os etc modules.?

I want to build a program which deals with strings,database(sqlite3,mysql,Oracle),data structures,File I/O and System paths. and can run on Windows,Linux and Mac when re compiled on that platform.
and I want it to be console based.

Please don't recommend me to do it in other programming languages, I want the C folks to answer please.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Well, as long as you use the standard C library, all is well. The GNU C Library (glibc) is one implementation of the C standard, and for example Microsoft has their own implementation of it.

From a user's (your) perspective, the impelementation doesn't matter. If you for example

```
#include <stdio.h>
```

then you can, on any standards-compliant platform, call the `fopen()` and then use `fread()` for file i/o. Or any other standard C function.

Linux, Mac and Windows are all standards compliant (i.e. have implemented the ISO C) and thus the standard functions do the same thing on all platforms. The filepaths that you pass to `fopen()` are the same, too. The fact that Windows uses backslash ( \ ) in the filepath instead of the Unix way (forward slash, / ) doesn't matter: on Windows, in your C program, you use the Unix-style notation.

Answer (score 0):

For C library functions, I suggest you ensure that you use functions within the [POSIX standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/). This will (at least in theory) guarantee compatibility with other POSIX platforms.

If you are programming on linux using `glibc` (i.e. the normal C library), the documentation thereof is reasonably good at pointing out what are GNU extensions, but the POSIX standard (referenced above) is the gold standard.

For other libraries, you'll have to look to the library in question.

Remember that if there are specific areas of incompatibility, you can use `#ifdef`'s etc around those bits, and keep the machine specific elements in specific files.

To the specific points you mentioned:
* The POSIX regexp functions (`regcomp`, `regexec`, `regerror`, `regfree`) are part of the POSIX standard.
* Most of the string manipulation functions (e.g. `strstr`) are part of the POSIX standard. Some (e.g. `asprintf`) are GNU extensions.
* SQL connectivity is not provided by the C library. You will need a specific C library to deal with your SQL connection, or to use something like `libdbi`. You'll need to look at the specific library to see what support there is on other platforms.

In particular, be careful with path manipulation on windows (think about slashes vs backslashes, and drive letters), specifically dealing with how they are input by the user and what is passed to the function.